# YEAR/MODEL Technique BMX frame

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike, bmx, technique

I own this Technique BMX frame and need help determining which frame i own. Serial number is M12903.

serial number underneath right rear fork[image: frame in question]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how do people end up owning these frames?

Comment: If you're positive about the manufacturer, ask them.   https://techniquebmx.com/

Comment: It's definitely a Technique. A monocoque frame would be pretty difficult and costly to fake. I do question if that Shopify site has anything to do with the original Technique. Seems someone else may have acquired the brand (possibly Peddle Power bmx in Riverside California). That being said they may know some historical facts.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations on the beautiful bmx frame.

You can tell which model Technique you have by the top tube length:

- Mini:  18-inch
- Expert:  19-inch
- Pro:  20.5-inch
- Pro XL:  21.5-inch
- Pro Cruiser:  21.5-inch (few made, made for 24-inch wheels)

Since your serial starts with an 'M' I'm going to guess it's a mini with an 18-inch top tube (I'd love to hear if that's not the case).

Unfortunately I wasn't able to find any info on decoding their serial numbers. The year would likely be late 90s or early 2000s. The only other serial I could find ended in 27, so I assume the last two digits aren't the year.